# Appcenter: Failed to obtain authentication

Tags: appcenter, release-hera

Just did a fresh install of ElementaryOS Hera (5.1.2) and after updating, upgrading and installing some apps, also installing elementary-tweaks. I get this error (screenshot attached) and after removing all the custom added PPAs, cleaning the sources.list file and all, still can't fix the error, any help?

Additional information, i can search, find apps and see updates but i can't install any updates or new apps. I can install everything through the terminal but nothing from the AppCenter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Logout

Reboot

Reload AppCenter

Comment: Seems all i needed was a reboot/relog. Might leave this post up in case anyone else faces this. Thanks bud.